# Where is it best to install a Windows program in the Ubuntu Operating system?

Tags: microsoft-office

I'm planning to install Microsoft Office on my Ubuntu 14.04. I was wondering if there is a location which is best to use for installing programs made for Windows.

I'd like to keep my office when upgrading to a newer version of Ubuntu, so I guess I shouldn't put it in the root partition, in order not to get it overwritten?

Answer (score 2):

I would advice against this.

When using another operating system use the software included in that operating system. In case of Microsoft Office there is a perfect solution: Libre Office. It has close to 100% compatibility and supports xls(x) and doc(x). It is different yes and will need you to relearn using office (since LO does things a bit different).

> if there is a spot, which is best to use for installing programs, made for windows.

Software from 3rd parties should be installed in `/opt/` but this is for Linux software. There is no place to install Windows software in Ubuntu/Linux since that software is not made for it. We do not have a Windows runtime environment in Linux itself.

If you need to use Windows software you can do this using a tool called WINE. It is an attempt to mimic Windows but it is difficult to set up, hard to get working perfectly. It will make you cry if you want to use it for anything than the basic tools. Experience is important when dealing with WINE.

If you need Windows software and can not do without use Windows for it. Optinally you can do this with a dual boot (Windows side by side with Ubuntu) or with virtualization (Windows installed in virtualbox installed in Ubuntu).

But if I was you I would start with Libreoffice. You can even install it in Windows, get used to it and then decide to fully switch to Ubuntu. Same goes for other software: most of our software also is available on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Good luck!  Most MS programs will not run in Ubuntu directly.  You can try Wine, PlayOnLinux a virtual machine such as VMPlayer or VirtualBox, or a dual boot.

Additionally, if you are just looking for the MS Office suite, you can run them online in a browser in a manner similar to google docs.

Answer (score 0):

your home directory? during and after upgrade files in your home directory are not touched
You will need [Wine](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/install-wine-1-7-20-ubuntu-linux/) program to install Windows applications and by default it keep all installed windows programs in your home directory

(not a part of this answer but, LibreOffice is good, free alternative to Windows Office)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Office works through the `wine` subsystem, which translates Windows system calls to native ones on-the-fly.  If you are not experienced with using it, I think it would be a good idea to use `PlayOnLinux` as a frontend to `wine`.  `PlayOnLinux` can be installed from the software center or by `sudo apt-get install playonlinux`.

Once `PlayOnLinux` is installed, perform the following steps.

1. Lower your expectations.
2. Run PlayOnLinux from your menu.
3. Pick `Install a program` from actions at top right.
4. Click `Office` at the top and choose your version of Microsoft Office from the list.
5. Click `Install` and follow the prompts.

At this point, PlayOnLinux will create the location to which Microsoft Office will be installed; during the process, accept the default install location (probably something starting with `C:\Program Files...`).  This will be mapped automatically to a directory under your user directory.

Assuming all goes well (not a foregone conclusion), you'll be able to run your Microsoft Office applications from your menu.

This same/similar procedure can be used to install almost any wine-compatible Windows application.  That step one above is always the most important.